# AngularJS ng-pattern regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have the following input field that accepts the price as a value.

```
input{ 
    type="text" 
    name="price" 
    np-currency=true
    ng-model='price'
    ng-pattern="/[$,.]\d*$/"
}
```

This pattern`("/[$,.]\d*$/")` makes the input field invalid for `$25.34@@@C%34` which is correct however just 25 also becomes invalid thats because it does not have either $ or , or. How do I make it optional?

I need `$25.00` or `25` as valid but not `$25.00$%#$%%@@`.

requirement: any digits `$`, `,` `.` are valid

I really appreciate any suggestions on this regular expression.

Comment: Try `"/^[$]?\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/"` (if you also need to let the empty string as valid). Note that the requirements are not clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Might wanna add `,` too.

Comment: Is `,`  a digit grouping symbol (thousand separator)? Or is it Russian/Polish/etc. decimal separator? What about just `,,,,,,`? There are lots of questions I can ask looking at the current requirements.

Comment: It's USD and the max allowed value is 100,000

Comment: Why not just use `type="number"`, and assume the `$` as implicit? what other logic are you using in your app that you care if there is a `$` at the beginning or not, or how many separators there are?  besides that, if you are going to do math using the value, then `text` doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Try `ng-pattern="/^[$]?(?:\d{0,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d{4,})(?:\.\d+)?$/"`

Comment: well that did it partially, its still valid for `56.34$` which should be invalid.

Comment: [My fiddle say it works ok](http://jsfiddle.net/xh70ffmy/2/). Can you share yours?